# I have a mapping method that accepts a callback as an argument but I keep getting this error JavaScript

Tags: javascript, function, scope

I'm totally confused as to why 'cb' is not a function in my case.

Basically I have a 'Tree' constructor

```
 this.value = value;
 this.children = [];
};

Tree.prototype.addChild = function (value){
 var newInstance = new Tree(value);
 this.children.push(newInstance);
}

Tree.prototype.map = function(cb){
 var copyTree = new Tree(this.value); //1
 copyTree.value = cb(copyTree.value);
 for (var i = 0; i < this.children.length; i++){ // i = 0; 2                 i = 0's value is 2
   copyTree.addChild(new Tree.prototype.map(cb(this.children[i].value)))
 }

 return copyTree;
}
```

and then in the console I've passed in

```
var root1 = new Tree(1)
var branch1 = root1.addChild(2);
var branch2 = root1.addChild(3);
```

Now every time I invoke

```
var newTree = root1.map(function (value) {
                        return value * 2 })
```

I keep getting this error.

```
VM1769 Script snippet %231:13 Uncaught TypeError: cb is not a function
    at new Tree.map (VM1769 Script snippet %231:13)
    at Tree.map (VM1769 Script snippet %231:19)
    at <anonymous>:1:21
```

I know that my mapping method might not be right but just the fact that 'cb' is not a function confuses me, I'm passing in an anonymous function on the .map call but.. 'cb' is not a function? Why is that?

Answer (score 0):

Inside `.map`, you have an array of trees to copy inside `this.children`. Since the array is composed of trees, those trees already have a `.map` method which you can call to create a copy of that tree. Change

```
copyTree.addChild(new Tree.prototype.map(cb(this.children[i].value)))
```

to

```
copyTree.addChild(this.children[i].map(cb))
```

```js
function Tree(value) {
  this.value = value;
  this.children = [];
};

Tree.prototype.addChild = function(value) {
  var newInstance = new Tree(value);
  this.children.push(newInstance);
}

Tree.prototype.map = function(cb) {
  var copyTree = new Tree(this.value);
  copyTree.value = cb(copyTree.value);
  for (var i = 0; i < this.children.length; i++) {
    copyTree.addChild(this.children[i].map(cb))
  }
  return copyTree;
}

var root1 = new Tree(1)
var branch1 = root1.addChild(2);
var branch2 = root1.addChild(3);


var newTree = root1.map(function(value) {
  return value * 2
})
console.log(newTree);
```

More readably, using modern syntax:

```js
class Tree {
  constructor(value) {
    this.value = value;
    this.children = [];
  }
  addChild(value) {
    const newInstance = new Tree(value);
    this.children.push(newInstance);
  }
  map(cb) {
    const copyTree = new Tree(this.value);
    copyTree.value = cb(copyTree.value);
    for (const child of this.children) {
      copyTree.addChild(child.map(cb))
    }
    return copyTree;
  }
}
const root1 = new Tree(1)
const branch1 = root1.addChild(2);
const branch2 = root1.addChild(3);


const newTree = root1.map(value => value * 2);
console.log(newTree);
```

Comment: so I editted my code and I still got the same error... thats why Im confused, although the one you posted does exactly what I was looking for but Im still confused as to why mine isn't working properly.. I keep getting the same error "cb is not a function"

Comment: Your `Tree.prototype.map(cb(this.children[i].value))` will *invoke* the `cb` function immediately and pass its return value (a number) as the next `cb` argument to `.map`. But `cb` should be a function, not a number. (in addition to other problems)